# how to use password with spaces in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a problem to implement my project in gitlab in my FTP I am using this code that works perfectly, but the password for the connection to ftp has space

Something like this: 12345 6789

As you can see this password has a space between 5 and 6.

How can I use a password like this with this code that I leave below?

```
deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror -Rev ./ ./htdocs  --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob README.md --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
    - master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of ways to do it.

have you configured the $PASSWORD on CI/CD variables right?
Change it to `file` instead to `var` (in the variable screen) and try this

```
deploy:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
    - lftp -c "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$(cat $PASSWORD) $HOST; mirror -Rev ./ ./htdocs  --ignore-time --parallel=10 --exclude-glob README.md --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .git/"
  only:
    - master
```